# Convertir un string a un formato date de php a sql server

Tags: php, sql-server

mi problema es el siguiente, realize una vista en sql server que me trajera los datos faltantes en una tabla de mi base de datos jalandolos de otra base de datos.
el problema surge cuando quiero hacer una insercion masiva en php , todo lo inserta bien excepto las fechas, me sale el mensaje de "Necesitas una clase de formato de fecha para insertar este valor " y ya intente convertirlo a formato de fecha en varias maneras para que no falle la insersion, pero solo me salen 3 ecenarios
1.- no inserta, 2.- El formato de fecha me da 1900-01-01, 3.- El formato de fecha me da 1970-01-01
el codigo que estoy usando es esto

```
introducir el código aquí
 public function crea_fechas($fec_insumo){
        $fecha = gmdate('Y-m-d', strtotime($fec_insumo)); 
        return $fecha;
    }
public function Crea_RDFDA_por_expediente($num,$user,$No_analista,$id_aut,$num_det,$fec_res,$fec_inven,$RDFDA){
        include_once "conexion.php";
        $BD = new ConexionSQL();
        $con = $BD->ObtenerConexionBD();
        
        $fec_det = self::crea_fechas($fec_res);
        $fec_inv = self::crea_fechas($fec_inven);  
        $query = "  INSERT INTO [Determinante] (
            id_expediente,
            id_autoridad,
            id_empleado,
            estatus_cred,
            fojas,
            fecha_inv,
            fecha_determinante,
            num_determinante,
            RDFDA,
            fecha_alta,
            user_alta,
            estatus,
            id_proc)
    values(
    1514,
      652, 
      15,
      'A',
        0,
        '$fec_inv' ,
       '$fec_det',
        '$num_det',
        '$RDFDA',
        GETDATE(),
        '$user',
        'A',
        1)";
        $prepare = sqlsrv_query($con, $query);
        if ($prepare) {
          return true;
        } else {
            return print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),false);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Pon un ejemplo del formato que tienen las fechas que quieres convertir (me refiero al parámetro `$fec_insumo`), es dependiendo de eso que debes crear una fecha correcta.

Comment: Ya me quedo disculpa por eso no conteste el resultado era ->format('d-m-Y); para complementar y darle formato a las fechas pero si ya quedo